# Create number of lists based on hierarchy

Tags: python, data-structures

What I want to do is convert a table that defines a hierarchy into a number of lists (or dictionaries or whatever)

So here is what my source data looks like:

```
THING     THINGS_PARENT
100       None
200       100
300       200
400       100
500       None
600       300
```

Extending that slightly to include the level of each THING (as at the outset I don't know what the level is)

```
THING     THINGS_PARENT   LEVEL
-----     -------------   -----
100       None            1
200       100             2
300       200             3
400       100             2
500       None            1
600       300             4
```

and what I want to end up with is

```
level1list = [100, 500]
level2list = [200, 400]
level3list = [300]
level4list = [600]
```

What I am struggling with is the fact the the list of THINGS may be 1 or 10,000 and the number of levels may be 1 to unknown.

Thanks in anticipation

EDIT

---

So I have been working on this myself, and here is where I am up to:

```
parentdict = {100: None, 200: 100, , 300: 200, 400: 100, 500: None, 600:300}
levelcount = 1
templist = []
for thing, parent in parentdict.iteritems():
    if parent is None:
        templist.append(thing)
levelsdict[levelcount] = templist
```

Now I can't work out how to iterate through the dictionary until I have all of the lists I need.

Comment: Use `dict` for the task

Comment: Use a `list` for the result. `levels = [level1list, level2list, .. ]`

Comment: Thanks, but I obviously didn't explain myself very well.  The data may run to 10,000's of lines, and I need to construct the lists from the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fathomed the answer, but I am sure it could be more pythonic.  Here is my answer, please feel free to improve:

```
parentdict = {100: None, 200: 100, 300: 200, 400: 100, 500: None, 600: 300}
def getParent(p_child):
    level = 1
    thisparent = parentdict[p_child]
    while thisparent is not None:
        thisparent = parentdict[thisparent]
        level += 1
    return level



levelsdict = {}
for thing in parentdict.keys():
    thinglevel = getParent(thing)
    if thinglevel in levelsdict:
        templist = levelsdict[thinglevel]
        templist.append(thing)
        levelsdict[thinglevel] = templist
    else:
        levelsdict[thinglevel] = [thing]

print levelsdict

{1: [100, 500],2: [200,400], 3: [300], 4: [600]}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION AFTER MORE INFORMATION**

The following solution should work even with no constraints on how the input is presented.

```
parentdict = {100: 200, 200: None, 300: 200, 400: 150, 500: None, 600: 300, 150: 100}
from collections import defaultdict
leveldict = defaultdict(int)
levellistdict = defaultdict(list)

def get_level(thing):
    if thing in leveldict:
        return leveldict[thing]
    elif parentdict[thing] == None:
        leveldict[thing] = 1
    else:
        parent_level = get_level(parentdict[thing])
        leveldict[thing] = 1 + parent_level
    return leveldict[thing]

for key in parentdict:
    leveldict[key] = get_level(key)
    levellistdict[leveldict[key]].append(key)

print leveldict
>> defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {100: 2, 200: 1, 300: 2, 400: 4, 500: 1, 150: 3, 600: 3})
print levellistdict
>> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [200, 500], 2: [100, 300], 3: [150, 600], 4: [400]})
```

@Peter Its a little better than the solution you posted as the `get_level` function uses information that it has previously computed. As in if I have already computed the level of my parent I can use that to compute my level instead of traversing all the way up to find the root element (with parent as `None`). Your solution is perfectly fine as well but this one would be faster computationally and better when you have more levels. Let me know how this works.

**SOLUTION BEFORE EDIT**

For the toy example you have something like this should solve your purpose:

```
parentdict = {100: None, 200: 100, 300: 200, 400: 100, 500: None, 600:300}
from collections import defaultdict
leveldict = defaultdict(int)
levellistdict = defaultdict(list)
for key in parentdict:
    if parentdict[key] == None:
        leveldict[key] = 1
        levellistdict[1].append(key)
    else:
        level = leveldict[parentdict[key]] + 1
        leveldict[key] = level
        levellistdict[level].append(key)

print leveldict
>> defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {100: 1, 200: 2, 300: 3, 400: 2, 500: 1, 600: 4})
print levellistdict
>> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [100, 500], 2: [200, 400], 3: [300], 4: [600]})
```

The solution maintains two dicts, one for the LEVEL of each THING and another for a list at each LEVEL. For any new item - if its parent is None we assign level 1 and if not we add 1 to the level of the parent and append to appropriate list.

Note that this assumes that the order of the THINGs in the dict is such that THINGS_PARENT always occurs before THING. Depending on how you are loading the data this can be ensured by using an OrderedDict if needed. I will leave it to you figure that out.

Comment: A good answer, but unfortunately we don't know that the parent will always come before the child.  Worse, something with an ordinal position before it's child is possible (so 200 could be the parent of 100)

Comment: @PeterHolliday edited the answer to remove the constraint on the order. Your solution is fine as well. I have pointed out how this solution can be faster. Let me know how it works for you

Answer (score 0):

I would use a 2 dimensional list for this. If you don't know a 2 dimensional list is a list within a list.

Assuming you parse through each line of text and store it in variable `currLine`, you can do this:

```
level = currLine.split()[2]
```

What this does is split a line, like:

> "100       None            1"

into

> ["100","None","1"]

After you've done that you access the 3rd element of that list, or index 2, which is the level and store it in the `level` variable. Now that you can take a line and identify its level, you can loop through every line in the table and tell what level it is.

This part is inefficient but I couldn't think of another way to do it. Hopefully another user can comment on a way to optimize this, but you need to loop through your table twice, once to find the maximum value, and another time to store values. 
Assuming you find the maximum level to be 5, you can use that to create the master list.

```
masterList = [[]] * 5
```

This creates a list like so:

> [[],[],[],[],[]]

Basically what that does is create 5 lists inside one big list. Now you can loop through your table again, find out which level the object is, then add it to that index of `masterList`

```
level = currLine.split()[2]
masterList[level].append(currLine.split()[0])
```

For example if you take line "100       None            1", you split it into ["100","None","1"], store its 3rd element in level, then append the first element ("100") in master's 1st list. This updates masterList to be:

> [["100"],[],[],[],[]]

After looping through all your text files and storing them in masterList based on level, you can later store each list of master into another list.

```
level1list = masterList[0]
level2list = masterList[1]
...
level5list = masterList[4]
```

Its due noting that the index of masterList will be one less than the level because of how lists work. I hope this helps. Good luck Peter!